why sp_ExecuteSql output parameter returns null from linked server when procedure shows correct value in results panel
I am trying to get SQL version from a linked server and save it in a variable, but the query runs fine and showed me the result but when I review the output variable is Null.
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @servername NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(500); 

SET @servername = 'SERVERNAME';
SET @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([' + @servername + '], ''SELECT @@VERSION'')';
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@queryresult NVARCHAR(500) OUT', @result OUT; 

SELECT @result;


Put @queryresult into the query @cmd
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @servername NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(500); 

SET @servername = 'SERVERNAME';
SET @cmd = 'SELECT @queryresult=ver FROM OPENQUERY([' + @servername + '], ''SELECT @@VERSION ver'')';
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@queryresult NVARCHAR(500) OUT', @result OUT; 

SELECT @result;


You are seriously overcomplicating this. You don't need OPENQUERY double-embedded in dynamic SQL, you can just put ServerName.master.sys.sp_executesql in a variable and call EXEC @proc @cmd.
As mentioned by others, you also need to set the output parameter.
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @servername sysname;
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(300); 

SET @servername = 'SERVERNAME';
SET @cmd = 'SELECT @result = @@VERSION';
DECLARE @proc NVARCHAR(1000) = @servername + '.master.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC sp_executesql @proc @cmd,
    N'@result NVARCHAR(300) OUT',
    @result = @result OUT; 

SELECT @result;

But if you just want to view the result, you can also do this without using an output parameter at all.
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @servername sysname;

SET @servername = 'SERVERNAME';
SET @cmd = 'SELECT @@VERSION';
DECLARE @proc NVARCHAR(1000) = @servername + '.master.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC sp_executesql @proc @cmd;

